# Is gRPC client an API gateway for the gRPC servers?

Tags: go, microservices, grpc

My goal is to understand what is gRPC Client is for.

**My questions:**

1. Is gRPC client created by both the backend engineer (Go) and another engineer (Java) to communicate with the gRPC services?

   i.e. the company hired a new backend engineer and he specialized in Java. He created a new service (i.e. service-garage, written in Java) and also created the garage.proto file. He need the service-user (written in Go), so he do `protoc --java_out=. --grpc--java_out=. user.proto`. By doing so, he can call the `service-user` method in Java inside the service-garage.
2. Is gRPC client an API gateway?

   i.e. There are 2 services, service-user (written in Go) and service-garage (written in Java). There should be one backend engineer that write the gRPC client, so the frontend engineer can use this API gateway to send request to.

**My current thought:**

1. microservices use multiple ports i.e. 7000 and 9000

i.e. a service-user and a service-garage

[services/service-user/main.go](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/go_blitz/blob/master/day1/pm-3/services/service-user/main.go) on port 7000

```
func main() {
    srv := grpc.NewServer()
    var garageSrv GaragesServer
    model.RegisterGaragesServer(srv, garageSrv)

    log.Println("Starting RPC server at", config.SERVICE_GARAGE_PORT)

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", config.SERVICE_GARAGE_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not listen to %s: %v", config.SERVICE_GARAGE_PORT, err)
    }

    log.Fatal(srv.Serve(l))
}
```

[services/service-garage/main.go](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/go_blitz/blob/master/day1/pm-3/services/service-garage/main.go) on port 9000

```
func main() {
    srv := grpc.NewServer()
    var userSrv UsersServer
    model.RegisterUsersServer(srv, userSrv)

    log.Println("Starting RPC server at", config.SERVICE_USER_PORT)

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", config.SERVICE_USER_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not listen to %s: %v", config.SERVICE_USER_PORT, err)
    }

    log.Fatal(srv.Serve(l))
}
```

2. microservices use multiple repositories

   1. repository for gRPC protocol buffers (accessed by gRPC client and gRPC servers)
   2. repositories for services (ie service-uer and service-garage`
   3. repository for gRPC client with port 80 and 443. The frontend web developer or frontend mobile developer can send request to port 80 and 443 ie `localhost:80/user/register` and `localhost:80/user/list`
3. gRPC client is the API endpoint that the frontend web developer or frontend mobile developer send request to.

[client-2/main.go](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/go_blitz/tree/master/day1/pm-3/client-2)

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/user/register", user.Register)
    mux.HandleFunc("/user/list", user.List)

    mux.HandleFunc("/garage/add", garage.Add)
    mux.HandleFunc("/garage/list", garage.List)

    err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", mux)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
}
```